# JAX-WS & Tomcat: storing in InitialContext not possible?

Tags: java, tomcat

**Intro** I'm writing a web service using JAX-WS, and deploying it in Tomcat. With a lot of difficulties  I finally had some code written.

**Problem** Unfortunately, when trying to run it I get the following error:

```
Context is read only
```

**Setting** I'm writing a web service that queries multiple databases and returns a single result. For that purpose, in the `init()` method (marked with `@PostConstruct`), I create a series of `DataSources` that I add to the context.

This is how I create the pool ([based on Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)) and after its creation I add it to the context ([based on this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jdbc/section6.html)):

```
@PostConstruct
private void init(){
  PoolProperties props = new PoolProperties();
  props.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + ...);
  props.setUsername(...);
  props.setPassword(...);
  props.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
    "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

  DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
  dataSource.setPoolProperties(propos);

  Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
  ctx.bind("java:/comp/env/dbpool", dataSource);
}
```

And later I use it:

```
@WebMethod
public Result performQuery(QueryParameters params){
  Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
  (DataSource) source = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/dbpool");
}
```

I deploy the web service on a Tomcat 7 server.

**Question** I understand after Google-ing that I cannot write into the Context on Tomcat. But how else could I solve this? From what I understand about JAX-WS I cannot just have a private variable holding a `DataSource`, right? I have to pass that `DataSource` using a `Context`, right?

Comment: You're using the *Plain Ol' Java* way, I'm not sure if will work (looks like didn't). I'll recommend following the *As a Resource* way (it worked for me in the past) and then you just have to execute the code from your tutorial `Context ... DataSource ...` etc.

Comment: Note that this problem is not related to Web Services nor their development. You can have the same problem on a simple web application.

Comment: One more thing: Tomcat **is not** a Java EE server, is just a Servlet container. If you want to use a full fledged Java EE server use JBoss or GlassFish or TomEE (as open source alternatives).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I really have to read more into the subject...

Comment: An additional thing (maybe you'll get tired of me). I tend to use [this tutorial](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) instead of the one you propose in your link.

Comment: Nope, I never get tired of such good comments! :-) Thanks for the link to the tutorial, I will adjust my code according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InitialContext` is writable from the Tomcat code only, not from your client code. You *must* add your `DataSource` to your `context.xml` and it'll work.